# Comma Before Parentheses in Variable Assignment

Tags: powershell

I'm using the [S.DS.P PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/S.DS.P/1.8.2) in a PowerShell script of mine. In it, I have to create the following object:

```
$ADUserEntry = @{"distinguishedName"=$null;"objectClass"=$null;"sAMAccountName"=$null;"unicodePwd"=$null;"userAccountControl"=0};
```

In the [documentation of the module](https://github.com/jformacek/S.DS.P/blob/f2c9edec90f361f4ff9c3328a4e76179f6fec284/S.DS.P.psm1#L575), it's stated that I have to do the following assignment to the `unicodePwd` field of a variable created using this object:

```
$obj.unicodePwd = ,([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("$randomPassword") -as [byte[]]);
```

Notice how there's a comma before the first parentheses. What is that comma doing there?

Comment: it's the `comma operator`. [*grin*] it makes an array with the item to the left as an object in the new array. that can be used to prevent the automatic unrolling of an array by wrapping the 1st array in a 2nd one ... and the 2nd one is the one that gets unwrapped. you can see the MS docs on that here ... about_Operators | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) has pointed out, what you're seeing is the ***unary form*** of the (unfortunately named) **["comma operator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-)**, i.e., **PowerShell's *array-construction operator***.

The *unary form* creates a *single-element array* that wraps its (one and only) operand; the array's type is `[object[]]`, as usual in PowerShell:

```
$arr = , 'foo'  # wrap string 'foo' in a single-element array
$arr.GetType().Name # the array's type -> 'Object[]'
$arr[0].GetType().Name # the type of the array's one and only element -> 'String'
```

Note that while you can even wrap arrays that way, PowerShell's operator-precedence rules require a literal array operand to be enclosed in `(...)`:

```
# OK - wraps array 1, 2 in a single-element array.
$arr = , (1, 2) 

# !! DOES SOMETHING DIFFERENT:
# Creates a 2-element array whose 1st element is integer 1 wrapped in a
# single-element array
$arr = , 1, 2
```

The *binary form* constructs an array from the operands, as expected:

```
$arr = 1, 2, 3  # 3-element array whose elements are integers 1 and 2 and 3
```

---

As an aside, re the specific command shown:

> `,([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("$randomPassword") -as [byte[]])`

Neither `,` nor `-as [byte[]]` are needed in this scenario, because
`[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes()` *directly* returns a `[byte[]]` array.